I know this is a dumb one, Only one run after copying uf2
Working through examples & creating a new stepper motor system. Yeah, I know it drops the drive, etc. and runs. But after that it doesn't run again. Did I miss something? Do I need to wire the run line to ground, etc. Or is this an issue of using while(true) kinda trickery?

My crystal ball doesn't seem to be working so I can't see what you did.

This is true of any C/C++ examples. Copy the compiled uf2, board resets & runs. But if unplugged and replugged, er nothing. I'm sure I missed a step.

yes, the step you missed is the one where you explain clearly what you are doing

What about your power supply? Is that working fine?
